Measuring voltage of a terminal when the reference paths that become different from switched using a MOSFET
I am designing a Power Monitoring and Protection board that is going to sit in between a 5-Series (~70V) Lead Acid Battery and a load. This board has a Energy Monitoring IC from TI - INA237AQDGSRQ1 and a STM32F091C8Tx as the MCU. The load current will be 50A continuous and 80A peak. The idea is to get the data from INA237 and switch 4/5 parallel MOSFETs when any protection condition is hit. The board needs to protect against:

Over voltage during charge.
Under voltage during discharge.
Overcurrent in charge.
Overcurrent in discharge.

So essentially this board will function as a BMS. The MOSFETs are going to be turned on or off only when a protection event will occur. Please find the block diagram below:

My question is: If the MCU opens the MOSFET thereby disconnecting the BAT- which is my system ground, will INA237 be able to detect the voltage on the Pack+ terminal? The scenario is that, for ex, if the pack enters undervoltage condition and the MCU switches the MOSFET open, then the charger and this board will have no common reference path. How can I measure the voltage on the Pack+ terminal to detect a CCCV charger being connected so that I can close my MOSFETs to allow charging?
I can use the ADC on the MCU also to measure the voltage without necessarily using INA237. I can add another specialized IC if there exists one aswell. Please advise on the options I have.
Edit: Adding the schematic based on Mr. Simon Fitch's suggestions for anyone to use as reference.


On this post my query is on how to perform voltage measurement on a system having a different ground. In the post you have tagged I was asking how to select an architecture. Now I have decided on an architecture. I have pointed that out in the last section of the post.

You can detect a drop in potential on the right side of the MOSFET, which (assuming the MOSFET is off) would happen when PACK is connected:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The trick here is resistor R3, which causes node Y to be +70V or less than +70V, depending on the state of MOSFET M1 and/or PACK connection. The rest is just a functional diagram of how you might process a change in potential at Y, using something akin to a comparator. There are of course many other ways to detect a change in Y potential, or change in current through R3.
The comparator, and the potential divider R1 & R2 are permanently powered from the battery, regardless of MOSFET state. R1 and R2 provide an arbitrary threshold potential at X.
When MOSFET M1 is off, and no PACK is connected, R3 pulls comparator input Y high to +70V, and the comparator output P is low.
When the MOSFET is on, or the PACK is connected, it will cause potential at Y to fall. If it falls below the threshold at X then the comparator output P goes high.
I won't go further to suggest how you'd implement the comparator, except to say that whatever you use, it will have to be tolerant of a 70V supply. In any case, the heart of the detection mechanism is simply R3, and it's up to you how you process the voltage across it, or current through it.
Here's another idea, not requiring anything special, except a 70V tolerant transistor:

simulate this circuit
When Q1 is off, potential at P is held at 0V by R2. When PACK is connected, PACK- is pulled low, switching on Q1, which raises the potential at P. This is clamped to a 5V maximum (with respect to ground), suitable for use with a microcontroller.
For clamping to a lower voltage like 3.3V, I wouldn't really trust a 3.3V zener diode, since their regulation is generally terrible. It might be better to clamp to something higher, like 12V, and use a potential divider to drop down to 3.2V:

simulate this circuit
The values shown produce a stable +3.2V at P, with battery voltage between 40V and 100V:


Thank you for the excellent suggestions, kind sir. I have decided to go ahead with the second idea and have made the schematic using actual components and added it as an edit. I know might be asking for too much, but I would really appreciate if you could take a quick look at it and see if everything checks out. Thanks again!

@AbhijithVNarayan Zener diodes under 4.7V have terrible regulation, so if you want to clamp to 3.3V, better do something like in my last update.

Okay, I will make the suggested changes. Can you please also see if the PNP transistor that I have selected also checks out.
